# I've written a test class which is giving me only 63% code coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

[image]Need a minimum of 90% to deploy to production can any one help me with the below code.

```
@isTest(seeAlldata=true)
public class Consent_Test{ 
/**
*   Utility class used for generating Dummy Data for Test Methods
**/
  public class DummyData{

/**
*   Description : This method will generate List of Consents with Dummy Data
*
*   @withIds : Do you want returned records with generateId? If null then false
**/
 Public List <Consent__c> getConsents(Integer totalrecords, Boolean withIds)
{
    List<Consent__c> retList = new List<Consent__c>();
    if(withIds == null)
        withIds = false;

    for(Integer i=0;i<totalrecords;i++)
    {
        Consent__C a = new Consent__C(Name = constructTestString(20));
        retList.add(a);
    }
    if(withIds)
        insert retList;

    return retList;

}
/**
*   This method is used to generate Random String of supplied length
*/
public  String constructTestString(Integer length) {
    Blob blobKey = crypto.generateAesKey(128);
    String key = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(blobKey);
    return key.substring(0,length);
}
 }

    public static testMethod void consentInsertMethod(){
    Id accRecId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Person').getRecordTypeId();
    Id accProvRecId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Provider').getRecordTypeId();
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.FirstName = 'Ladieda';
    acc.Lastname = 'TestLastname'; 
    acc.PersonEmail = '12345678@bencom.nl';
    acc.Type = 'Person';
    acc.RecordTypeId = accRecId;
    insert acc;
    Account prov = new Account();
    prov.Name = 'Provider A';
    prov.Type = 'Provider';
    prov.RecordTypeId = accProvRecId; 
    prov.ProviderType__c = 'Energy';
    insert prov; 

    Package__c pack = new Package__c();
    pack.Provider__c = Prov.Id;
    pack.Name = 'Elec0';
    pack.Bencom_Product_ID__c = 'elec0' ;
    pack.Type__c = 'Electricity'; 
    pack.Bencom_Product_ID_SubPackage_1__c = null;
    pack.Bencom_Product_ID_SubPackage_2__c = null;
    pack.Duration__c = 24;
    pack.PriceCondition__c = 'Vast';    
    insert pack;

    Consent__C cnsnt = new Consent__C ();
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(cnsnt);        
    consent122 cnt = new consent122(sc);
    consent122.WrapConsent wp = new consent122.WrapConsent();
    wp.Salutation = cnsnt.Salutation__c;
    wp.accid=cnsnt.Account__c;
    wp.FirstName=cnsnt.FirstName__c;
    wp.Initials=cnsnt.Initials__c;
    wp.LastNamePrefix=cnsnt.LastNamePrefix__c;
    wp.LastName=cnsnt.LastName__c;
    //wp.ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum=cnsnt.String.valueof(ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum__c);
    //wp.ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum=cnsnt.ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum__c;
    wp.MeterTariffChoice=cnsnt.MeterTariffChoice__c;
    wp.PhoneNumber=cnsnt.PhoneNumber__C;
    wp.EmailAddress=cnsnt.EmailAddress__c;
    wp.Main_Street=cnsnt.Main_Street__c;
    wp.Main_Number=cnsnt.Main_Number__c;
    wp.Main_PostalCode=cnsnt.Main_PostalCode__c;
    wp.Main_City=cnsnt.Main_City__c;
    //wp.Exclude_from_Surveys= cnsnt.Exclude_from_Surveys__c;
    wp.Main_addition=cnsnt.Main_Addition__c;
    wp.LastConsentName=cnsnt.name;
    cnt.startDate=system.today();
    cnt.endDate=system.today();
    cnt.consentFilter();
    cnt.generateConsentlist();
    }
   }
```

Class

```
/**
* @author Satya Srinivas N C 
* @description 
*/ 
public class consent122 {
public date startDate{get;set;}
public date EndDate{get;set;}
public Map<id,WrapConsent> allCon{get;set;}

public consent122(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    allCon = new map<id,WrapConsent>();
}

public void consentFilter() { 
    // clear the previous results to add freshly fetched results.
    allCon.clear();
    for(Consent__C consent:[select account__r.id, id, name, Salutation__c, FirstName__c, Initials__c, LastNamePrefix__c, LastName__c, 
                            ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum__c, ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum__c, MeterTariffChoice__c, PhoneNumber__C, EmailAddress__c, 
                            Main_Street__c, Main_Number__c, Main_Addition__c, Main_PostalCode__c, Main_City__c, Exclude_from_Surveys__c from Consent__c where 
                            CreatedDate >= :startDate AND CreatedDate < :EndDate.addDays(1) and ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum__c > 0 and Status__c = 'Processed' 
                            ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC]) {
                                // WrapConsent wCon = allCon.get(consent.account__r.id);
                                WrapConsent wCon = new WrapConsent();

                                // If the account is already present, then we need to just update the LastConsentName and exit the loop.
                                if (allCon.containsKey(consent.account__r.id)) {
                                    continue;
                                }

                                wCon.accid = string.valueof(consent.account__r.id);
                                wCon.LastConsentName = consent.name;
                                wCon.Salutation = consent.Salutation__c;
                                wCon.FirstName = consent.FirstName__c;
                                wCon.Initials = consent.Initials__c;
                                wCon.LastNamePrefix = consent.LastNamePrefix__c;
                                wCon.LastName = consent.LastName__c;
                                wCon.ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum = string.valueof(consent.ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum__c);
                                wCon.ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum = string.valueof(consent.ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum__c);
                                wCon.MeterTariffChoice = consent.MeterTariffChoice__c;
                                wCon.PhoneNumber = string.valueof(consent.PhoneNumber__C);
                                wCon.EmailAddress = consent.EmailAddress__c;
                                wCon.Main_Street = consent.Main_Street__c;
                                wCon.Main_Street = consent.Main_addition__c;
                                wCon.Main_Number = string.valueof(consent.Main_Number__c);
                                wCon.Main_PostalCode = consent.Main_PostalCode__c;
                                wCon.Main_City = consent.Main_City__c;
                                wCon.Exclude_from_Surveys = string.valueof(consent.Exclude_from_Surveys__c);
                                // system.debug('wrapCon ' + wCon); //checkin Log your wrapCon is generated Properly with all fields

                                allCon.put(wCon.accid, wCon);
                            } //Closing of for loop

    // Count the consents in the time period
    for (AggregateResult groupedResults: [SELECT Count(Id)ids, Account__r.Id accids FROM Consent__c where CreatedDate < :EndDate.addDays(1) 
                                          and ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum__c > 0 and Status__c = 'Processed' GROUP BY Account__r.Id]) {

                                              //for (AggregateResult groupedResults: [SELECT  Count(Id)ids, Account__r.Id accids FROM Consent__c where Status__c = 'Processed' GROUP BY Account__r.Id]) {
                                              String aID = String.valueof(groupedResults.get('accids'));
                                              WrapConsent wrapCon = allCon.get(aID);

                                              if (wrapCon == null) {
                                                  wrapCon = new WrapConsent();
                                                  allCon.put(aID, wrapCon);
                                              } 

                                              wrapCon.coutOfid = String.valueof(groupedResults.get('ids'));
                                              for(Consent__C oldConsent:[select account__r.id, id, name, Salutation__c, FirstName__c, Initials__c, LastNamePrefix__c, LastName__c, 
                                                                         ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum__c, ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum__c, MeterTariffChoice__c, PhoneNumber__C, EmailAddress__c, 
                                                                         Main_Street__c, Main_Number__c, Main_Addition__c, Main_PostalCode__c, Main_City__c, Exclude_from_Surveys__c from Consent__c where 
                                                                         account__r.id = :aID and ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum__c > 0 and Status__c = 'Processed' ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 1]) {
                                                                             wrapCon.id = oldConsent.id;
                                                                             wrapCon.FirstConsentName = oldConsent.name;
                                                                             wrapCon.FirstElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum = string.valueof(oldConsent.ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum__c);
                                                                             wrapCon.FirstElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum = string.valueof(oldConsent.ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum__c);

                                                                         }
                                          }
}

public void generateConsentlist() {
    consentFilter();
}

public class WrapConsent{
    public string ID{set;get;}
    public string coutOfid{set;get;}
    public string accid{set;get;}
    //public string name{set;get;}
    public string Salutation{set;get;}
    public string FirstName{set;get;}
    public string Initials{set;get;}
    public string LastNamePrefix{set;get;}
    public string LastName{set;get;}
    public string ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum{set;get;}
    public string ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum{set;get;}
    public string MeterTariffChoice{set;get;}
    public string PhoneNumber{set;get;}
    public string EmailAddress{set;get;}
    public string Main_Street{set;get;}
    public string Main_Number{set;get;}
    public string Main_PostalCode{set;get;}
    public string Main_City{set;get;}
    public string Exclude_from_Surveys{set;get;}
    public string Main_addition{set;get;}
    public string FirstConsentName{set;get;}
    public string FirstElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum{set;get;}
    public string FirstElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum{set;get;}
    public string LastConsentName{set;get;}

} 
}
```

Comment: Which lines aren't covered?

Comment: The coverage says it is 63% and 45 out of 71 lines are covered, but the method has passed without any errors. I'm unable to insert the created date it could be one of the issues.

Comment: The lines that are not covered are 22,24,31-48,51,95,96,104  of the class - unable to fix it - request assistance

Comment: We can"t see the line numbers in your code so it's a bit difficult to know which are these lines.

Comment: I will copy paste the lines. // Sorry I've enclosed an image depicting the lines of the coverage that is not being covered

Comment: Try this:- https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EFozgUAD

Comment: I've tried this but it does not resolve the issue

Comment: Anywat, you shouldn't use @isTest(seeAlldata=true), otherwise you cannot be sure that the same coverage that you have in sandbox will be also in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making a few changes in the trigger that was used to update have been able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You need to remove line 68 and add below lines in your test class.

```
Consent_Test.DummyData innerClassVar = new Consent_Test.DummyData(); 
Consent__C cnsnt = innerClassVar.getConsents(1,true)[0];
```

As you are passing consents record without inserting in standard controller and making query on them. but the record is not inserted so you want be getting any result in query.
Also put proper values in consent record while inserting in test class which satisfy your further conditions in query filter and put same values on your apex class variables(startDate , EndDate).

Let me know if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: I've tried the above but it still gives me the same result.

Comment: Can you please update your code above so that I can check.Also have you added filter values in your test class?